# Is there a memory leak in my C++object pool

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my object pool code, where T::Cleanup() is used to initialize the Member variable in the T class,

```
template <typename T>
class ObjectPool
{
public:
    ObjectPool(std::size_t size)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            T* obj = new T();
            m_objs.push_back(obj);
        }
    }
    virtual ~ObjectPool()
    {
        for (auto iter = m_objs.begin(); iter != m_objs.end(); iter++)
        {
            delete (*iter);
        }
        m_objs.clear();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<T> getObject()
    {
        T* obj = iGetObject();
        if (obj != nullptr)
        {
            return std::shared_ptr<T>(obj, [this](T* ptr)->void
                {
                    ptr->T::Cleanup();
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
                    m_objs.push_back(ptr);
                });
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::deque<T*> m_objs;
    mutable std::mutex m_lock;

    T* iGetObject()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_lock);
        if (!m_objs.empty())
        {
            T* obj = m_objs.front();
            m_objs.pop_front();
            return obj;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Here is how I use object pool, in Worker class, one worker thread will call startWork() to collect DiagnosticInfo into _diag2, then when finish, it will call finishWork() to move objects from _diag2 to _diag1.

```
class DiagnosticInfo
{
public:
    explicit DiagnosticInfo() = default;
    ~DiagnosticInfo() = default;
    void Cleanup()
    {
        _name = L"";
        _value = L"";
        _count = 0;
    }
private:
    CString _name;
    CString _value;
    int _count;
};
using DiagnosticInfoPtr = shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>;

class ProcessDiagnostic
{
public:
    ProcessDiagnostic(bool bCreateObject = false)
    {
        if (bCreateObject)
        {
            _pool = new ObjectPool<DiagnosticInfo>(1000000);
        }
    }
    ~ProcessDiagnostic()
    {
        _diagnostics.clear();
        if (_pool)
        {
            delete _pool;
            _pool = nullptr;
        }
    }
    void InsertDiagnostic(CString& name, DiagnosticInfo& info)
    {
        if (_pool)
        {
            auto pDiagnostic = _pool->getObject();
            _diagnostics[name].insert(info);
        }
    }
    void Cleanup()
    {
        _diagnostics.clear();
    }
public:
    map<CString, set<DiagnosticInfoPtr>> _diagnostics;
    ObjectPool<DiagnosticInfo>* _pool;
};
using ProcessDiagnosticPtr = shared_ptr<ProcessDiagnostic>;

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker()
    {
        _diag1 = make_shared<ProcessDiagnostic>();
        _diag2 = make_shared<ProcessDiagnostic>(true);
    }
    ~Worker();
public:
    void finishWork()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _diag1->Cleanup();
        _diag1->_diagnostics = std::move(_diag2->_diagnostics);
    }

    void startWork()
    {
        _diag2->Cleanup();
        while (count--)
        {         
            CString name;
            DiagnosticInfo info;
            //do something to get name and diagnostic info
            _diag2->InsertDiagnostic(name, info);
        }
    }

private:
    mutex _mutex;
    ProcessDiagnosticPtr _diag1;
    ProcessDiagnosticPtr _diag2;
};
```

After running the above code for a period of time, using umdh to grab the callstack of memory allocation, it was found that there are many following contents.
Where Object Pool.h, 45 refers to the tenth line of function std::shared_ptr getObject() of ObjectPool class
Diagnostic.DataProvider!<lambda_e1682d1063100b59987acd670871cd4c>::operator()+66 (C:\Build\Diagnostic.DataProvider\ObjectPool.h, 45)

- 6a120 ( 6a120 -     0)   6a12 allocs    BackTrace1501D028
- 6a12 (  6a12 -     0)  BackTrace1501D028   allocations

```
ntdll!RtlWalkHeap+194
ntdll!RtlCaptureStackContext+796A
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+3E
ucrtbase!malloc_base+26
Diagnostic.DataProvider!operator new+1A (D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\heap\new_scalar.cpp, 35)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Default_allocate_traits::_Allocate+C (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xmemory, 79)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Allocate<8,std::_Default_allocate_traits,0>+29 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xmemory, 235)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::allocator<DiagnosticInfo *>::allocate+19 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xmemory, 834)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::deque<DiagnosticInfo *,std::allocator<DiagnosticInfo *> >::_Emplace_back_internal<DiagnosticInfo * const &>+C9 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\deque, 1117)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::deque<DiagnosticInfo *,std::allocator<DiagnosticInfo *> >::push_back+1B (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\deque, 1130)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!<lambda_e1682d1063100b59987acd670871cd4c>::operator()+66 (C:\Build\Diagnostic.DataProvider\ObjectPool.h, 45)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Ref_count_resource<DiagnosticInfo *,<lambda_e1682d1063100b59987acd670871cd4c> >::_Destroy+3F (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\memory, 1173)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref+32 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\memory, 1110)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Ptr_base<DiagnosticInfo>::_Decref+1B (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\memory, 1336)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>::~shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>+F (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\memory, 1619)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>::`scalar deleting destructor'+F
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >::destroy<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> >+D (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xmemory, 691)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *>::_Freenode<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+3B (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 380)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+3F (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::_Erase_head<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,void *> > >+24 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 753)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> >,0> >::~_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> >,0> >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 1088)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >::~set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > >+F
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >::~pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >+12
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >::`scalar deleting destructor'+F
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >,void *> > >::destroy<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > > >+D (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xmemory, 691)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_node<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >,void *>::_Freenode<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >,void *> > >+3B (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 380)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > > > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >,void *> > >+3F (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
Diagnostic.DataProvider!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > > > >::_Erase_tree<std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<CString const ,std::set<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo>,DiagnosticInfo::PtrCompare,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<DiagnosticInfo> > > >,void *> > >+25 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xtree, 745)
```

Through the results of umdh, I feel that after calling the object pool, there is an alloc, but no dealloc. However, I'm not sure whether it is an error in the object pool or the implementation of deque itself will result in such a call stack.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly it is not going to be an error in `std::deque`.

Comment: `int main() { ObjectPool<int> o1(10); ObjectPool<int> o2 = o1; }` -- I think there is a lot more to worry about than memory leaks.  What happens at the ending `}`?

Comment: Replace your object pool with a trivial one which just calls `std::make_shared<T>()` and see if the problem persists. Aside: do not return `nullptr` when allocation fails, throw an exception instead.

Comment: @wohlstad How do you think objects are returned to the pool?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit good point, missed that.

Comment: Have you used Valgrind or any other tool to look for leaks?  You should include the tool's output in the question.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `ObjectPool<int> o2 = o1;` should fail to compile. `ObjectPool` contains a `std::mutex` member, and is therefore neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: When called with `bCreateObject=false`, `ProcessDiagnostic` doesn't initialize `_pool` member, whether to null or otherwise. But elsewhere, it checks `_pool` for null. Whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `_diagnostics[name].insert(info);` in `InsertDiagnostic` shouldn't compile. Shouldn't `pDiagnostic` be actually used in there somewhere?

Comment: I don't see anything remarkable in the call stack. `map<CString, set<DiagnosticInfoPtr>>` is being destroyed, which in turn destroys all the `set<DiagnosticInfoPtr>`, which in turn runs your custom deleter on all the `DiagnosticInfoPtr` shared pointers, which in turn pushes all the `DiagnosticInfo` pointers back onto the deque in the object pool. What exactly do you believe should be deallocated but isn't? What makes you feel there's an error or a problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Because I have created 1 million pieces and frequently call startWork() and finishWork(), after repeating several times, umdh will have the Call Stack above, so I guess there's some memory leak in my object pool, maybe I am not right.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from "call stack above" to "memory leak". I don't see anything in that call stack that suggests a memory leak. What exactly do you find concerning about this call stack?

Comment: `ObjectPool<DiagnosticInfo>* _pool;` never get destructed before `ProcessDiagnostic` is destructed. Finding many allocations might not be wrong but just expected. I'll suggest to provide an [mre].